# Is there an easy way to specify table locations in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to align five or so tables at the top of a page so that they are vertically aligned with one another.  I've been doing this by zooming in and overlapping the table lines (since they change colors when you do that) and then I just move it over a bit to separate the tables.  Is there an easily way to do this in Oracle SDDM?  Perhaps there is a hidden X,Y coordinate system that I'm not finding where you can specific where to put them?

I did manage to find a coordinate system that showing the entire page with dots every few pixels apart, but this does not help since the software does not auto place tables to be in line with one another.  If anyone has an easy way to set these tables up in line with one another, please lend a hand!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: CTRL + L or CTRL + T will left align or top align objects.  (Be sure to shift select multiple objects though.